# Golang record DB column changes

Tags: go, types

I have a DB table `MyTable` and a history record table `HistoryRecord`.

```golang
type MyTable struct {
    MyInt    int    `gorm:"my_int"`
    MyString string `gorm:"my_string"`
    MyPolicy Policy `gorm:"my_policy"`
}

type Policy struct {
    Maximum *int  `json:"maximum,omitempty"`
    Minimum *int  `json:"minimum,omitempty"`
    Avail   []int `json:"avail,omitempty"`
}

type HistoryRecord struct {
    Field string
    Value any
}
```

I save MyPolicy of Policy type as JSON in DB row.

I want to generate records of changes. For example, If I change `MyInt`, then generate new record `HistoryRecord{Field: "my_int", Value: <new_myint_value>}`. Since the HistoryRecord is saved in DB, it saves changed column name in `Field` and its new value in `Value`. Value can be int, string, Policy, or anything.

I have to convert record values to DTO so that a user can see in more familiar format.
If I use type assertion, I have to code like this:

```golang
switch record.Field {
case "my_policy":
    record.Value.(MyPolicy).Maximum // Some code to DTO
case "my_int":
    record.Value.(int)  // ...
case "my_string":
    record.Value.(string) // ...
}
```

But it is not flexible and too static. Is there any way to get typed value or the data that I want to get? I was thinking using of interface, generic, etc, but stuck on type. It is little bit hard to write my question understandable, but I think generate records of DB field changes is not an extraordinary thing.